# Visual Format Language: "Swift" Image constraints not working

Tags: xcode, swift, visual-format-language

I'm having an issue with building constraints. I'm very new using Visual Format Language. I need help. I put my constraints for two images the height is okay but the horizontal placement is off. They seem to be placed at different lengths with different devices. I'm trying to keep them centered in a button but the two images are just obeying the -70- on the left and right side always despite the width of the phone. How do I tell it to adjust to the width of the phone? Oh consider I have images setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

```
// Constraint Views
        let views = ["view": view,
                     "topHeader": topHeader,
                     "topBannerView": topBannerView,
                     "backGroundView": backGroundView,
                     "wolLogoView":wolLogoView,
                     "backGround2View": backGround2View,
                     "pictureView": pictureView,
                     "wolMottoView": wolMottoView,
                     "menuButton": menuButton,
                     "buttonMenuView": buttonMenuView,
                     "featListings": featListings,
                     "scrollView": scrollView,
                     "button1": button1,
                     "busLogoView": busLogoView,
                     "button2": button2,
                     "classLogoView": classLogoView,
                     "button3": button3,
                     "forwardLogoView": forwardLogoView,
            ]

        // CONSTRAINTS -----------------------------------------------------

        // backGround
        var constHBackground = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[backGround2View]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHBackground)
        var constVBackground = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-17-[backGround2View(>=100)]-0-[backGroundView(==backGround2View)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVBackground)


        // topHeader
        var constHHeader = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view]-(<=0)-[topHeader(==view)]", options: .AlignAllTop, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHHeader)
        var constVHeader = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view]-(<=0)-[topHeader(17)]", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVHeader)


        // topBannerView
        var constHBanner = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[topBannerView(==view)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHBanner)
        var constVBanner = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-17-[topBannerView(50)]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVBanner)

        // wolLogo
        var constHWolLogo = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-55-[wolLogoView(>=0)]-60-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHWolLogo)
        var constVWolLogo = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[wolLogoView(28)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVWolLogo)

        // picture view
        var constHPic = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[pictureView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHPic)
        var constVPic = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView(>=0)]-0-[backGroundView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVPic)

        // wolMotto
        var constHWolMotto = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[wolMottoView(>=0)]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHWolMotto)
        var constVWolMotto = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-69-[wolMottoView(35)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVWolMotto)

        // menuButton
        var constHMenuButton = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[menuButton(40)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHMenuButton)
        var constVMenuButton = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-22-[menuButton(40)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVMenuButton)

        // buttonMenuView
        var constHButtonMenu = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[buttonMenuView(==menuButton)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHButtonMenu)
        var constVButtonMenu = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[buttonMenuView(==menuButton)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVButtonMenu)

        // featListings
        var constHFeatListing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[featListings]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHFeatListing)
        var constVFeatListing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView][featListings][scrollView]-130-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVFeatListing)

        // button3
        var constHButton3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(>=0)-[button3(100)]-(<=0)-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHButton3)
        var constVButton3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView][button3][scrollView]-130-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVButton3)

        // forwardLogoView
        var constHForwardLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(>=0)-[forwardLogoView(23)]-(<=0)-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHForwardLogoView)
        var constVForwardLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView][forwardLogoView(>=0)][scrollView]-130-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVForwardLogoView)

        // scrollView
        var constHScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHScrollView)
        var constVScrollView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView(>=0)]-130-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVScrollView)

        // button1 and button2
        var constHButton1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-15-[button1(<=220)]-20-[button2(==button1)]-15-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHButton1)
        var constVButton1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView(>=0)]-20-[button1(80)]-25-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVButton1)
        var constVButton2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView(>=0)]-20-[button2(80)]-25-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVButton2)

        // busLogoView and classLogoView
        var constHBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[busLogoView]-100-[classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-50-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constHBusLogoView)
        var constVBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView(>=0)]-20-[busLogoView(<=50)]-45-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVBusLogoView)
        var constVClassLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView(>=0)]-20-[classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-45-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(constVClassLogoView)
```

I know this is hard to look at haha. Like I said this is my first time doing constraints. Sorry!

Comment: Can you show what your view is supposed to look for? Also, you're over constraining your views. In the third set you only need... `"V:[scrollView]-20-[classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-45-|"`

Comment: Also, what's the size of the view that you are placing the views in? I don't think you need to constrain the width of the `busLogoView` to `<=50` because the width will be inferred from the fact that it is equal width to the `classLogoView`.

Comment: I'm not sure what view your talking about? Oh the I thought you were supposed to call the constraints on the other views so it can take to account of the other view such as pictureView and scrollView which are vertically above the button and image

Comment: let me put more information up! sorry for being vague

Comment: I added an answer as it's easier to explain what I mean than in comments :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just editing your constraints to remove over constraining views I can get it down to...

```
// busLogoView and classLogoView
var constHBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-70-[busLogoView][classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-70-|", 
                                                                       options: nil,
                                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                                       views: views)
view.addConstraints(constHBusLogoView)
var constVBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-85-[pictureView]-30-[scrollView]-20-[busLogoView(<=50)]-45-|",
                                                                       options: nil,
                                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                                       views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVBusLogoView)
var constVClassLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[scrollView]-20-[classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-45-|",
                                                                         options: nil,
                                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                                         views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVClassLogoView)
```

A few notes about the changes.

1. Adding a `>=0` constraint to width or height is redundant because all views have to have positive size in AutoLayout. So you can just not add a constraint at all.
2. In the second set of constraints you already position the picture view and scroll view. You don't need to position them again in the third set.
3. In the first set you added a `]-0-[` space. You can do this with `][`.
4. In the first set of constraints you added an equal width constraint between the bus and class view. But you also said bus should be `<=50` and you also gave constraints that go all the way from the left to the right of the superview. This is dangerous because if the superview is more tan 240 (70 + 70 + 50 + 50) across then those constraints will conflict each other (class and bus cannot be the same width with bus being less than or equal 50 width because that cannot add up to more than 240).

I suspect it was possibly number 4 that was causing your problem (possibly not) but apply these fixes and let me know what happens.

**EDIT**

In fact, looking again it looks like you already have picture view and scroll view constrained elsewhere so you don't need picture view in here at all...

```
// busLogoView and classLogoView
var constHBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-70-[busLogoView][classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-70-|", 
                                                                       options: nil,
                                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                                       views: views)
view.addConstraints(constHBusLogoView)
var constVBusLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[scrollView]-20-[busLogoView(<=50)]-45-|",
                                                                       options: nil,
                                                                       metrics: nil,
                                                                       views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVBusLogoView)
var constVClassLogoView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[scrollView]-20-[classLogoView(==busLogoView)]-45-|",
                                                                         options: nil,
                                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                                         views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVClassLogoView)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! I'll apply the changes to see what I get!

Comment: Okay I put the code in and it made it all wack. I'll show you the full code im working with.

Comment: I was able to set the images to compensate the horizontal constraints but it stretches my images

Comment: You need to show what it is you are trying to do. Show a picture of the view you are trying to lay out. Working with broken code will only get broken code. lol

Comment: @ThomasM can you just show a picture (or sketch or anything) of the view you're trying to lay out. Also, it's much easier doing this sort of thing in Interface Builder.

Comment: Agreed! haha yea Ill throw in something visually. Give me one sec